# Count before order, skip and take

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework together with Unit-of-work and repository pattern.

For a function with ordering, pagination, etc. I use the following code:

```
stammdatenEntityModels =
    _unitOfWork.StammdatenRepository.Get()
                .Where(
                    s =>
                    s.Geloescht == false &&
                    ((s.Auftraggeber != null && s.Auftraggeber.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.SerienNummer.Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.StammdatenKunde != null && s.StammdatenKunde.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.BeginnVos.HasValue && s.BeginnVos == dateTime) ||
                    (s.VosDauer != null && s.VosDauer.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.Geraetewert.HasValue && s.Geraetewert.Value.ToString().Contains(keyword))
                    ))
                .OrderBy(orderBy)
                .Skip(inputModel.EntriesToDisplay*(inputModel.Page - 1))
                .Take(inputModel.EntriesToDisplay)
                .ToList();
```

Now I need to know the numbers of records, but before the skip and take (for pagination) is performed.

Therefore I have the same code again:

```
totalCount = _unitOfWork.StammdatenRepository.Get()
            .Count(
                s =>
                s.Geloescht == false &&
                ((s.Auftraggeber != null && s.Auftraggeber.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                (s.SerienNummer.Contains(keyword)) ||
                (s.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                (s.StammdatenKunde != null && s.StammdatenKunde.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                (s.BeginnVos.HasValue && s.BeginnVos == dateTime) ||
                (s.VosDauer != null && s.VosDauer.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                (s.Geraetewert.HasValue && s.Geraetewert.Value.ToString().Contains(keyword))
                ));
```

Unfortunately this leads to a lot of redundance and my query is performed twice. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the redundancy. What you can do is to cache the count result for the specific parameters (keyword, dateTime) a certain amount of time and use it again at subsequent calls to deliver paginated (skip, take) results from the StammDatenRepository.

This way you only have the overall count-call one time for specific parameters.

Found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197115/using-linq-to-return-the-count-of-items-from-a-query-along-with-its-resultset) where a respected member states:

> Thinking about it from a SQL point of view, I can't think of a way in
>   a single normal query to retrieve both the total count and a subset of
>   the data, so I don't think you will be able to do it in LINQ either.

So, I really think you have to cache some counts results to increase performance. You know best how to do it for your specific situation and if it's worth it at all...